# ParameterNotFoundException: You have requested a non-existent parameter "database_accounts_driver"

Tags: symfony, symfony-2.1

when I make update for a symfony2 project using compser.phar :

```
php composer.phar update
```

I have this error when I run the project after updating :

```
ParameterNotFoundException: You have requested a non-existent parameter "database_accounts_driver".
```

here is my config.yml :

```
# Doctrine Configuration
doctrine:
dbal:
    default_connection:       default
    connections:
        default:
            driver:   "%database_driver%"
            host:     "%database_host%"
            port:     "%database_port%"
            dbname:   "%database_name%"
            user:     "%database_user%"
            password: "%database_password%"
            charset:  UTF8
        accounts:
            driver:   "%database_accounts_driver%"
            host:     "%database_accounts_host%"
            port:     "%database_accounts_port%"
            dbname:   "%database_accounts_name%"
            user:     "%database_accounts_user%"
            password: "%database_accounts_password%"
            charset:  UTF8
```

also my parameter.yml :

```
parameters:
database_driver:   pdo_mysql
database_host:     127.0.0.1
database_port:     ~
database_name:     symfony
database_user:     root
database_password: ~

mailer_transport:  smtp
mailer_host:       127.0.0.1
mailer_user:       ~
mailer_password:   ~

locale:            en
secret:            ThisTokenIsNotSoSecretChangeIt
```

and finally my appkernel :

```
$bundles = array(
        new Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\FrameworkBundle(),
        new Symfony\Bundle\SecurityBundle\SecurityBundle(),
        new Symfony\Bundle\TwigBundle\TwigBundle(),
        new Symfony\Bundle\MonologBundle\MonologBundle(),
        new Symfony\Bundle\SwiftmailerBundle\SwiftmailerBundle(),
        new Symfony\Bundle\AsseticBundle\AsseticBundle(),
        new Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\SensioFrameworkExtraBundle(),
        new JMS\AopBundle\JMSAopBundle(),
        new JMS\DiExtraBundle\JMSDiExtraBundle($this),
        new JMS\SecurityExtraBundle\JMSSecurityExtraBundle(),
```

Any Idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I can see, there is not database_accounts_driver defined in yout parameters.yml
You have database_driver, database_host, database_name... buy NOT database_ACCOUNTS_driver (and also not database_accounts_host, etc...)

If you want to use different parameters to default and account configuration you must define this in your parameters.yml:

```
parameters:
    database_driver:   pdo_mysql
    database_host:     127.0.0.1
    database_port:     ~
    database_name:     symfony
    database_user:     root
    database_password: ~

    database_accounts_driver:   pdo_mysql
    database_accounts_host:     127.0.0.1
    database_accounts_port:     ~
    database_accounts_name:     whatever
    database_accounts_user:     whatever
    database_accounts_password: blablabla

    mailer_transport:  smtp
    mailer_host:       127.0.0.1
    mailer_user:       ~
    mailer_password:   ~

    locale:            en
    secret:            ThisTokenIsNotSoSecretChangeIt
```

Comment: Note: Take into account that maybe if you write those lines in parameters.yml and then you update composer, if you had not written those lines too in the parameters.yml.dist maybe they can dissapear (because composer updates parameters.yml following the structure of parameters.yml.dist)